# Using a csv or similar to limit possible parameter inputs

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox, parameters

Is it possible to use the contents of a single column csv file to limit the list of acceptable inputs for a tool in a python toolbox? I'm aware that I can use the code below to achieve my requirements, but the list I need often varies outside of ArcGIS and outside of my control and therefore the code would need regular updates.

`options1 = [1, 2]
param0.filter.type = "Value List"
param0.filter.list = options1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try opening the csv and loading the values into a list.

```
import csv

param0.filter.type = "Value List"
with open('c:/pythontools/file.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    param0.filter.list = [item for sublist in list(reader) for item in sublist]
```

**Edit:** By default, the `list(reader)` returns a list, so we need to flatten the list of lists into a single list.

You will also want to fully specify the path of the csv file to avoid any path issues.

[This post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24662707/2258) has more details.

Comment: Thanks for your help Richard. Using the code above isn't working for me. I'm ending up with a little red cross on the tool's icon. Trying to run it produces an error box saying "Unable to execute the selected tool.".

Comment: I should point out that if I manually specify the options list, the tool works correctly, so the issue is being caused by the csv code.

Comment: @davehughes87, can you give the error message in full?

Comment: @davehughes87 I forgot the `list(reader)` returns a list even if there's just a single entry.  As the `filter.list` needs a flattened list, we need to sample out the values.  See updated code.

Comment: The tool runs fine without using the csv code. Adding the csv code means the tool is not placed in the correct folder and instead shows up with a red cross http://bit.ly/2cQvvKD. ArcMap suggests the syntax of the toolbox is correct and will still run all other tools. Attempting to run this tool results in the following window. http://bit.ly/2dpZBpi

Comment: @davehughes87 I tested the current code in my answer and it is working.  If you still get an error, you should try to leverage the `messages` within the execute function to see the nature of the exception.

Comment: Thanks Richard. The issue is I'm not getting as far as the execute function so I don't have any error codes to play with. Instead I get the pop up in my earlier comment. I think I'm closer to the solution thanks to your help and I'll report back if I find anything.

Comment: Pretty sure I made no changes and it's now working. Typical Friday. Cheers Richard!